# Eslint & Prettier conflicts

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

I am new in eslint and prettier. I have this simple example, when i use  "tabWidth": 4 in .prettierrc.json file. i saw error.I order to not have conflicts between them, i installed the eslint-config-prettier. But i still get errors.

**Files:**

**1. App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
function App() {
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

const lea = 15;

const loginHandler = (email, password) => {
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
};

const logoutHandler = () => {
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
};

return (
    <>
        <MainHeader isAuthenticated={isLoggedIn} onLogout={logoutHandler} />
        <main>
            {!isLoggedIn && <Login onLogin={loginHandler} />}
            {isLoggedIn && <Home onLogout={logoutHandler} />}
        </main>
    </>
);}
```

export default App;

**2. .eslintrc.json**

```
{
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
},
"extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "prettier"
],
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
},
"parser": "babel-eslint",
"plugins": ["react", "prettier"],
"rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"]
}}
```

**3. .prettierrc.json**

```
{
"arrowParens": "always",
"bracketSpacing": true,
"htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
"insertPragma": false,
"jsxBracketSameLine": false,
"jsxSingleQuote": false,
"printWidth": 86,
"proseWrap": "preserve",
"quoteProps": "preserve",
"requirePragma": false,
"semi": true,
"singleQuote": false,
"tabWidth": 4,
"trailingComma": "es5",
"useTabs": false,
"vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false}
```

**4. package.json**

```
{
"name": "react-complete-guide",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
    ]
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
    ]
},
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
}}
```

**5. error image**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlp2C.png)

Comment: Reorder your "extends" array in eslintrc.json to have the most specific configs at the end, The 2nd index overrides the 1st, the 3rd index overrides the 2nd and so on. hence keep the ones you want to apply at the end. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#extending-configuration-files.